# How to create separate Android build.gradle configs for Local tests vs Instrumented tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, junit4, junit5

In my build.gradle file I'd like to specify "useJUnitPlatform()" **only** for my Local tests but not for my instrumented tests. I currently have the following declared in my app build.gradle:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}
```

The problem is that "unitTests.all" will apply the 'useJUnitPlatform' setting to **all** unit tests, not just my Local tests. Is there any syntax to restrict that setting to my Local tests only?

Answer (score 0):

never mind. I found another solution. I left the *testOptions* args as they are but added this dependency:
*testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.8.2"*